# Making a Google Earth Engine app clickable

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am new to GEE and am trying to figure out how to make my map return the value of the rasters when the user clicks the map (like the inspector does in the code editor). I have 6 different raster layers each with one band and I would like to return the value of each upon the click. I have figured out how to return the coordinates upon clicking but I'm lost on how to return the values.

Here is my code for the coordinates

```
Map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair');

// Create a panel and add it to the map.
 var inspector = ui.Panel([ui.Label('Click to get info')]);
Map.add(inspector);


Map.onClick(function(coords) {
  // Show the loading label.
  inspector.widgets().set(0, ui.Label({
    value: 'Loading...',
    style: {color: 'gray'}
  }));
  
  inspector.widgets().set(0, ui.Label({value: 'Long: ' + coords.lon + ' Lat:'+ coords.lat}))

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduceRegion()` in your callback. You probably want to use `evaluate()` on the result to turn the server-side result into a client-side object to use in your label.

Read up on `reduceRegion()` [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_region) and client- vs server-side [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server).

```
var image = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2021_v1_9')
Map.addLayer(image, {bands: 'lossyear', min: 0, max: 21, palette: '#085CF8, #3C9E49, #98BB18, #F3CC1D, #FE8F7B, #F64497, #D70500'}, 'lossyear')
Map.onClick(function(coords) {
  // Show the loading label.
  inspector.widgets().set(0, ui.Label({
    value: 'Loading...',
    style: {color: 'gray'}
  }));
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point([coords.lon, coords.lat])
  image
    .reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
      geometry: point, 
      scale: Map.getScale() // Reduce at the scale of the map
    })
    .evaluate(function (data) { // Get the value in the background
      inspector.widgets().set(0, ui.Label({
        value: typeof data.lossyear === 'number'
          ? data.lossyear + 2000
          : 'no loss'
      }))
    })
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/32a279bc16a66d9504c335342639c8fc